# Historical quotes / prices of multiasset options

Tags: options, market-data, copula, multivariate

I am working on Lévy copulas, and I would like to try calibrating such techniques on real data. Where can I find quotes for multi-asset options? It could be exchange options or any other type of options, as long as it involves at least two assets. 
I have access to multiple universities libraries, and could access to a Bloomberg terminal if needed (I come from the theoritical side and am not used to handle real data).

Thanks!

Comment: Next time, ask fewer more targeted(specific) questions.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you check out this paper.

[Dynamic copulas: applications to financeeconomics](https://pastel.archives-ouvertes.fr/pastel-00003260/document)

In this paper they give examples that may be useful to you.

Specifically, the data that was looked at "CDOs (e.g. iTraxx and CDX)"

From page 5 of the paper
[image: daily variation of ABX index]

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck, as these days there are many exchange-traded funds that track indexes.  An option on one of these is therefore equivalent (for Lévy copula purposes at least) to an option on a weighted index of stocks.

So, for example, you can look at [options on SPY](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/funds-and-etfs/spy/option-chain) as options on a weighted sum of 500 different US stocks.  These are very liquid so you will get good prices at a wide range of strikes.  To get them from Bloomberg start by querying `SPY US EQUITY` for its options `CHAIN_TICKERS`.